# technique to find an arbitrary function when solve PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I need to solve a transport equation in the form
$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial t} + a(t) \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = b f + c$$ with $a(t) = A t$. From a reference book I took a solution $f = -c/b + e^{bt} \Phi(x - At^2/2)$ which contain an arbitrary function $\Phi(x - At^2/2)$. Unfortunately I cannot compose this function for the following conditions:

- initially $t = 0$ the function is zero everywhere $f(0, x) = 0$, which result in $\Phi = c/b$;
- at the boundary $x = 0$ the function is zero $f(t, 0) = 0$, which means that $\Phi = e^{-bt} c/b $.

The questions:

1. how to choose the function $\Phi$ in the example above?
2. is there a technique/algorithm for finding $\Phi$ which satisfy prescribed initial/boundary conditions?

Answer (score 2):

**If** you are imposing that at $x = 0$ the function $f(t,0) = 0$ **for all time $t$**, then necessarily that the only solution is $\Phi(t,x) = e^{-bt}c/b$. This is because your equation is a transport equation, and by prescribing data on $x = 0$ you have a well-posed evolution equation (when $a \neq 0$) where the "time variable" is $x$ and the "space variable" is $t$. And the unique solution is as given above.

But in general you probably **are not** looking for such a solution.

I expect what you are looking at is a problem on the first quadrant $x\geq 0$ and $t\geq 0$, with boundary condition prescribed at $x = 0$ *when $t \geq 0$* and with initial condition prescribed at $t = 0$ for $x \geq 0$.

Then what we have is that $$f(t,0)|_{t\geq 0} = 0 \implies \frac{c}{b} e^{-bt} = \Phi(-at)|_{t\geq 0}$$ This **only** gives the data for $\Phi(s)$ when $s \leq 0$. You are still free to prescribe $\Phi(s)$ for $s > 0$ **using the initial condition** $f(0,x)|_{x\geq 0}$. That is
$$ \Phi(s)|_{s\geq 0} = \left(f(0,s) + \frac{c}{b}\right)e^{-bt}$$

Note that when $a = 0$ the boundary condition **only** tells you that $\Phi(0) = c/b$. It tells you absolutely nothing about $\Phi$ for other values of the argument.

---

*Edit after original question was updated*

If you are now prescribing initial-boundary data, where $f(t,0) = 0$ for positive times and $f(0,x) = 0$ for positive $x$, then what we need to do is to see how this translates to conditions on $\Phi$. What you need to pay attention to is the fact that the initial and boundary data can only be used to prescribe the free function *on corresponding domains*. See below for an illustration.

Now $f(t,x) = - \frac{c}{b} + e^{bt}\Phi(x - At^2 / 2)$. We solve this to get
$$ \Phi(x - At^2/2) = e^{-bt}\left(f(t,x) + \frac{c}b \right) $$

Using that if $t > 0$ and $x = 0$, $f(t,x) = 0$. We have that

$$ \Phi(0 - At^2/2) = e^{-bt}\frac{c}b $$

for every $t > 0$. This tell you that, changing variables via $s = At^2/2$, we have that for every $s > 0$ (solving $t = \sqrt{2s/A}$)

$$ \Phi(-s) = e^{-b \sqrt{2s/A}} \frac{c}{b} $$

This specifies your arbitrary function along the negative real line.

Now we use that if $t = 0$ and $x > 0$, $f(t,x) = 0$. Plugging in we have

$$ \Phi(x - 0) = e^{-b\cdot 0} \frac{c}{b} = \frac{c}{b} $$

this means that $\Phi(x)$ for $x$ positive is equal to $c/b$.

In other words, you've almost gotten the answer already! What you need to pay attention to is the *domain* over which your initial/boundary can be applied to give you information. In this case, the *boundary* data can only be used to specify $\Phi$ along the negative real line, while the *initial* data can only be used to specify $\Phi$ along the positive real line.

Comment: you are right, I'm looking for a solution in the first quadrant, although I'm not sure if it is possible to prescribe physically meaningful initial conditions at $t=0$, and therefore I'm looking for a way to use the hint with $a = 0$.

Comment: What do you mean by "hint with $a = 0$"? If you don't prescribe initial conditions, then in the first quadrant **any function $\Phi$** such that $\Phi(-at)|_{t\geq 0} = \frac{c}{b}e^{-bt}$ (in particular, $\Phi(s)$ is **arbitrary** for $s > 0$ solves the PDE. You simply do not have enough information to specify $\Phi$ completely.

Comment: by hint I mean the solution of ODE obtained from PDE when $a$ is set to zero, i.e. the physically meaningful solution of ${df}/{dt} = c f + b$ is $f = -c/b (1 - e^{bt})$. I assume it should be also valid for PDE with properly chosen $\Phi$, therefore $\Phi$ should be reduced to $c/b$ when $a$ goes to zero.

Comment: Well, by saying "the physically meaningful solution of $f' = cf + b$ is $f = - c/b(1-e^{bt})$", you are throwing away a bunch of other solutions (the equation is time translation invariant, so $-c/b(1-e^{bt - d})$ are all solutions). By "physically meaningful" I presume you mean some set of conditions which _you have not mentioned in the question statement_. Like I said, if you want to further restrict your solution class you **have to provide** those additional information.

Comment: Also, you have to be even more careful with this "physically reasonable" business. If you formally take $a \to 0$ you end up with an ODE $f' = bf + c$ **which is not compatible with your boundary condition** $f(t,0) = 0$ unless $c = 0$. Lastly, I am beginning to wonder if what you are asking about is really [how to use the method of characteristics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics).

Comment: thank you for comments, but my question was about **algorithm of finding** the arbitrary function $\Phi$, not about a solution for this particular equation under particular initial/boundary conditions.

Comment: But an arbitrary function $\Phi$ is just that: it is arbitrary! Absent further conditions, any functions will do. There isn't one specific function, and hence there cannot be an algorithm to finding it.

Comment: Finally I need to have decimal number, not an arbitrary number, therefore I heed a particular function which satisfies to the boundary initial/conditions. The example of the conditions I provided in the question, hopefully it is clear now.

Comment: As I mentioned before, the ODE condition (second bullet point) is **incompatible** with the boundary condition prescribed at $x = 0$. Please clarify more what you are trying to do.

Comment: I changed the question to make it compatible. btw, could you please use less bold font in your replies? It is difficult to read.